# Cannot install gitlab using omnibus: Error executing action `run` on resource 'bash[migrate gitlab-rails database]'

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I've installed gitlab before and it was a pretty straight forward process, for the past week however the process outlines on the website fails at the `sudo EXTERNAL_URL="http://gitlab.example.com" apt-get install gitlab-ee` step.

The error seen:

```
    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `run` on resource 'bash[migrate gitlab-rails database]'
    ================================================================================

    Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
    ------------------------------------
    Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
    ---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20171024-7894-1sl10lo" ----
    STDOUT: rake aborted!
    PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:49:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    Tasks: TOP => gitlab:db:configure
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    STDERR: 
    ---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20171024-7894-1sl10lo" ----
    Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20171024-7894-1sl10lo" returned 1

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/database_migrations.rb

     51: bash "migrate gitlab-rails database" do
     52:   code <<-EOH
     53:     set -e
     54:     log_file="#{node['gitlab']['gitlab-rails']['log_directory']}/gitlab-rails-db-migrate-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S).log"
     55:     umask 077
     56:     /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake gitlab:db:configure 2>& 1 | tee ${log_file}
     57:     STATUS=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
     58:     echo $STATUS > #{db_migrate_status_file}
     59:     exit $STATUS
     60:   EOH
     61:   environment env_variables unless env_variables.empty?
     62:   notifies :run, 'execute[enable pg_trgm extension]', :before if omnibus_helper.service_enabled?('postgresql')
     63:   notifies :run, "execute[clear the gitlab-rails cache]", :immediately
     64:   dependent_services.each do |svc|
     65:     notifies :restart, svc, :immediately
     66:   end
     67:   not_if "(test -f #{db_migrate_status_file}) && (cat #{db_migrate_status_file} | grep -Fx 0)"
     68:   only_if { node['gitlab']['gitlab-rails']['auto_migrate'] }
     69: end

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/database_migrations.rb:51:in `from_file'

    bash("migrate gitlab-rails database") do
      action [:run]
      updated true
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      command "migrate gitlab-rails database"
      backup 5
      returns 0
      code "    set -e\n    log_file=\"/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/gitlab-rails-db-migrate-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S).log\"\n    umask 077\n    /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake gitlab:db:configure 2>& 1 | tee ${log_file}\n    STATUS=${PIPESTATUS[0]}\n    echo $STATUS > /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/upgrade-status/db-migrate-873248b1f0d3a7a5535771a3a1635803-3a712c3\n    exit $STATUS\n"
      interpreter "bash"
      declared_type :bash
      cookbook_name "gitlab"
      recipe_name "database_migrations"
      not_if "(test -f /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/upgrade-status/db-migrate-873248b1f0d3a7a5535771a3a1635803-3a712c3) && (cat /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/upgrade-status/db-migrate-873248b1f0d3a7a5535771a3a1635803-3a712c3 | grep -Fx 0)"
      only_if { #code block }
    end

    Platform:
    ---------
    x86_64-linux


Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 5 resources updated in 45 seconds
dpkg: error processing package gitlab-ee (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gitlab-ee
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is on Ubuntu 16.04LTS. How to resolve this and install gitlab?

I've also tried using older ways of installing gitlab (where gitlab was first installed then configured) however it still failed at the `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commonly the signal 137 indicate out of memory, check your system log:

```
grep -i memory /var/log/messages
```

Answer (score 0):

dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap bs=1M count=1024

mkswap /swap

swapon /swap

Comment: Hi FreezeSoul, could you please explain and develop your answer? You can be helped by the following tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer